# In Fortran2003, is 1D Assumed shape array interoperable with C?

Tags: fortran, dynamic-arrays, fortran-iso-c-binding, fortran2003

In Fortran 2003, the allocatable array is **not** interoperable with C. I suppose this has something to do with additional array information stored in memory which might disturb the C interpretation.

But what if I declare a dummy argument as 1D assumed shape array? for example

```
subroutine outter_subroutine(ma, size_ma)
integer  :: size_ma
integer  :: ma(size_ma)

call fortran_subroutine(ma)

end subroutine

!-----------------------------

subroutine fortran_subroutine(a)
integer, intent(in) :: a(:)
integer,(kind=c_int):: ierr
...
ierr = some_c_function(a)
...
end subroutine
```

The interface in fortran may like

```
interface
function some_c_function(a)
integer(c_int) :: a(*)
end interface
```

while in C, the prototype maybe

```
int some_c_function(int *a)
```

Will that conform the Fortran 2003 standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran 2003, assumed shaped arrays are not interoperable.

Assumed shaped arrays are not interoperable with C pointers to arrays in Fortran in general. They can be used when interoperating with C, but in a more complicated way using features in the standard `ISO_Fortran_binding.h` header from Fortran 2018, but that is much more involved than just using a C array pointer.

You can pass an assumed shape array (or any other) to an interoperable subroutine which has an assumed size argument (`a(*)`). A temporary array may have to be created by the compiler to be able to do that if the array is not contiguous.

Comment: So, is that mean if I declare the dummy argument with **assumed size** in a bind(c) interface, I can pass all kinds of 1D array into it, and the compiler take care of the rest thing?

Comment: Yes, that is true. But sometimes a temporary will have to be made.